# Indentation of the first paragraph in a section

Tags: formatting

Several papers that I have read only indent paragraphs that are not the first paragraph of a section:

```
1.1 Introduction

This is the first paragraph.

    This is the second paragraph.

    This is the third paragraph.
```

Is this a common convention? Are there rules for when to indent like this?

Comment: Yes, it's a fairly common typographical convention. It generally looks nicer, but someone with a better knowledge of typography (there should be at least one copy editor around here) can probably give you a sounder reason for that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about typsetting and has nothing to do with academia.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copied from [this answer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/3155) on writers.SE:

> [...] in Robert Bringhurst's Elements of Typographic Style, he states that
>   "opening paragraphs" should be "flush left" because "[t]he function of
>   a paragraph indent is to mark a pause, setting the paragraph apart
>   from what precedes it. If a paragraph is preceded by a title or
>   subhead, the indent is superfluous and can therefore be omitted".

Comment: "to mark a pause, setting the paragraph apart from what precedes it" - a more tangible reason is to tell apart a mid-paragraph pagebreak from one that coincides with a new paragraph, while looking at the second page.